# How can lm_sensors support Z370 chipset motherboards?

Tags: kernel, fan, sensors, lm-sensors

I've just bought a `Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. Z370 AORUS Ultra Gaming-CF`, using it with an `i7-8700k`.

Issue I have is that I can't get the fan speed and whatnot - just CPU temperatures with *coretemp*.

I've raised a bug on https://github.com/groeck/lm-sensors/issues/44 to ask the author if I should do anything, he suggested loading the driver `it87`. I have to say, when I run `sensors-detect`, it doesn't come suggested, hence not sure what I should do next.

I'm running kernel `4.10.0-42-generic`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me:

- Edit boot parameters in `/etc/default/grub`
- Add:

  ```
  acpi_enforce_resources=lax thermal.off=1 module_blacklist=eeepc_wmi
  ```
- Run:

  ```
  sudo update-grup
  ```
- Edit `/etc/modules`
- Add: `nct6775`
- Restart
- Run: `sensors`
- Optionally create `/etc/sensors.d/asus` as described in [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/a8j6ts/lmsensors_configuration_for_the_asus_prime_z370a/).

Sources:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/a8j6ts/lmsensors_configuration_for_the_asus_prime_z370a/
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lm_sensors

Answer (score 0):

Apparently is not possible without intervention with current Ubuntu distributions (and if things stay as those are even with next LTS 18.04).

If one wants now to use it, he/she will have to manually resort to downloading and compiling such driver from https://github.com/groeck/it87 and follow the instructions there.

This is less than ideal, that's why I've raised an Ubuntu question https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/662421 to update the `it87` driver.

**Edit**

As per suggestions, raised a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1740736 for Ubuntu folks to cater for latest driver...

Comment: You should learn to file bugs by running `ubutnu-bug` and how to write better descriptions too. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs